# Is there a rule for when to write numbers in full?

Tags: numbers, rules

I was recently taught that numbers should be written in full if:

- The number is between zero and ten.
- The number has three or less digits.
- The number is present at the start of a paragraph.

(Preferably a rule for Commonwealth English)

Comment: I would say "at the start of a sentence".

Comment: This is a matter of style; adhere to the guidance your editor or preferred style manual gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are free to choose your own style but you're looking for some Commonwealth English–friendly guidance in adopting a consistent personal system to follow, you might consider these recommendations from *The Oxford Guide to Style* (2003):

> **7.1.2 Figures or words?**
>
> In non-technical contexts, OUP style is to use words for numbers below 100. When a sentence contains one or more figures of 100 or above, however, use arabic figures throughout for consistency within the sentence: [examples omitted]. This convention holds only for the sentence where this combination of numbers occurs: it does not influence usage elsewhere in the text unless a similar situation exists.
>
> However, clarity for the reader is always more important than blind adherence to rule. And in some contexts a different approach is necessary. For example it is sometimes clearer when two sets of figures are mixed to use words for one and figures for the other, as in *thirty 10-page pamphlets*, *nine 6-room flats*. This especially useful when the two sets run throughout a sustained expanse of text (as in comparing quantities): [example omitted].
>
> ...
>
> In technical contexts, OUP recommends spelling out numbers below ten. Similar rules govern this convention: in a sentence containing numbers above and below ten, style the numbers as figures rather than words.

Like the *Chicago Manual of Style*, the *Oxford Guide* advises writers to spell out words for "indefinite or colloquial amounts" (such as "hundreds" or "a million"), and both style guides endorse spelling out numbers that appear at the beginning of sentences. But whereas Chicago (I believe) advises using figures for any whole-number quantity associated with units of measure such grams or liters or kilometers (or ounces or quarts or miles), Oxford makes no such recommendation, except when the unit of measure is abbreviated (as in "13 mm").

If you like the sound of Oxford's guidelines, you should consider obtaining a copy of the book because it includes many additional recommendations for handling numbers in specific situations that I've not included in this answer.

Comment: That is some amazing detail! I think I'll go with the Oxford style. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This varies. According to

> [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org)
>
> **9.2 Chicago’s general rule—zero through one hundred**
>
> In nontechnical contexts, Chicago advises spelling out whole numbers
>   from zero through one hundred and certain round multiples of those
>   numbers.
>
> **9.3 An alternative rule—zero through nine**
>
> Many publications, including those in scientific or journalistic
>   contexts, follow the simple rule of spelling out only single-digit
>   numbers and using numerals for all others.

For details, I'd suggest to get an online subscription (only $40/year), which gives one access to their forum.